# Accessing objects using index in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I access Objects when there are multiple objects are returned when using selectors?

```
     $('.copy_anim')[i].css({
      'position' : 'relative',
      'right'    : '-30px',
      'opacity'  : '0'
     });
```

using the above code says `$('.copy_anim')[i].css` is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the jQuery object (so you can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)) on the element at the `i` (0-based) index, use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this:

```
$('.copy_anim').eq(i).css({
  'position' : 'relative',
  'right'    : '-30px',
  'opacity'  : '0'
 });
```

If you just want to run it on *all* of the elements, just do:

```
$('.copy_anim').css({
  'position' : 'relative',
  'right'    : '-30px',
  'opacity'  : '0'
 });
```

This will run the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) on *all* `.copy_anim` elements...this is the default behavior of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you don't know the $.each in jQuery...

```
$('.copy_anim').each(function(index) {
    $(this).css({
      'position' : 'relative',
      'right'    : '-30px',
      'opacity'  : '0'
     });
  });
```

Is that it ?

Comment: And you can use index or whatever you called it, to choose which one you want to modify, etc... Here's the doc : http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Use each!

```
$('.copy_anim').each(arr,function(){
  $(this).css({
   'position' : 'relative',
   'right'    : '-30px',
   'opacity'  : '0'
  });
});
```